# Where "null" and "undefined" in array goes while converting array to string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

The snippet below explain the question

```js
//Outside array
console.log(String(undefined)); //undefined
console.log(String(null));      //null
console.log(String(5.55));      //5.55

//inside array

console.log(String([undefined])); // ""
console.log(String([null])); // ""
console.log(String([5.55])); //5.5
```

Why `null` and `undefined` shows different behavior when converted to string inside and outside the array.

Comment: Stringifying an array calls `.join()` on it. And when you call `.join()` on array `undefined` or `null` members are turned into empty strings. Are you asking for the rationally why `.join()` is implemented this way? Otherwise the answer is in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an array is implicitly coerced into a string, it calls `.join(,)` on the array:

[15.4.4.2 Array.prototype.toString ( )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2)

> 2. Let func be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of array with argument "join".

And the `.join` method *specifically* coerces null and undefined to the empty string:

[15.4.4.5 Array.prototype.join (separator)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5)

> 8. If element0 is undefined or null, let R be the empty String; otherwise, Let R be ToString(element0).

With values other than `undefined` or `null`, the element will just have `toString` called on it.

In other words, `null` and `undefined` are two special exceptions to the usual rule of just coercing the element to a string.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was looking for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

`String([])` is equivalent to `[].toString()`. And what `toString()` method do is `join()` elements with comma.

`null`, `undefined`, **they are converted to empty string** when `join()` by the definition.

> If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description